# jsx-control-statements - ReferenceError: Choose is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, package.json

I am using the jsx-control-statements node module for React with webpack.
Normally this works great, but when I copied my project to another folder and ran npm install using the same package.json as before, jsx-control-statements doesnt seem to be getting recognized by webpack.

jsx-control-statements is meant to desugar the tags in the render() and turn it into code react recognizes. Its not doing that in this case.

I see the final code running in the inspector that 'Choose' was never transpiled into valid code.

```
_react2.default.createElement(Choose, null,
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Choose is not defined
```

webpack.config.js and package.json and my source code for the app are unchanged. from a working app and this new one in another folder.

I have tried:

- installing jsx-control-statements manually locally and globally.
- copying and pasting the entire node_modules folder from the good project into this new project.
- Run eslint with eslint-jsx-control-statements plugin, no errors

Still the problem persists. I believe their is a problem in the building of project, but I am out of ideas what to try next.

Comment: What's the error you see in the developer console?

Comment: Also added it to my post - Uncaught ReferenceError: Choose is not defined

Comment: Can you upload code of your `webpack` config and `.babelrc` file?

Comment: Does running `npm ls` in both folders yield the same list for each?

Comment: It was my .babelrc file, my new project was missing it. copied that over from my current project fixed the error. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

The issue was simple as I felt it would be. I was missing a tiny .babelrc file which included a plugin reference to jsx-control-statements

```
{
    // my babel config here
    "plugins": ["jsx-control-statements"]
}
```

Just need to put this file at my root next to webapck.config.js